# I don't know what to put in the view placeholder

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I keep getting an error to insert "proxy: /GeometryProxy/" even when "proxy" is a state variable. I have the code for the preview below. I don't know what to put in the placeholder and I am confused. I have included my full code to review. Please look below.

```
struct MathematicallyMainController_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    MathematicallyMainController(proxy: // what do i put here?)
}
```

}

My full code:

This is where the problem with the 'var' is happening.

```
struct MathematicallyMainController: View {
@StateObject var tabBarModel = TabBarViewModel()
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
@State var selectedIndex = 0
@State var isSelectedA = false
@State var isSelectedB = false
@State var isSelectedC = false
@State var isSelectedD = false
@State var isSelectedE = false
@State var proxy: GeometryProxy
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        let bottomEdge = proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        switch selectedIndex {
        case 0:
            HomeViewController()
        case 1:
            BrowseView()
        case 2:
            RewardsView()
        case 3:
            EssentialsView()
        case 4:
            SchoolModeView()
        default:
            HomeViewController()
        }
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.regularMaterial)
                .colorScheme(colorScheme == .dark ? .dark : .light)
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Button {
                   selectedIndex = 0
                } label: {
                    if selectedIndex == 0 {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .blur(radius: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .frame(width: 60)
                                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
                            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    selectedIndex = 1
                } label: {
                    if selectedIndex == 1 {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .blur(radius: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                                .frame(width: 60)
                                .padding(.leading, 15)
                            Image(systemName: "rectangle.stack.fill")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                                .padding(.leading, 15)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "rectangle.stack.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    selectedIndex = 2
                } label: {
                    if selectedIndex == 2 {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .blur(radius: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                                .frame(width: 60)
                                .padding([.trailing, .leading], 15)
                            Image(systemName: "circle.dotted")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                                .padding([.trailing, .leading], 15)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "circle.dotted")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                            .padding(.trailing, 15)
                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    selectedIndex = 3
                } label: {
                    if selectedIndex == 3 {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .blur(radius: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .frame(width: 60)
                                .padding(.trailing, 15)
                            Image(systemName: "doc.text.image")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                                .padding(.trailing, 15)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "doc.text.image")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                            .padding(.trailing, 15)
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    selectedIndex = 4
                } label: {
                    if selectedIndex == 4 {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .blur(radius: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.purple)
                                .frame(width: 60)
                                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
                            Image(systemName: "graduationcap.fill")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "graduationcap.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                    }
                }
            }
            .colorScheme(colorScheme == .dark ? .dark : .light)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(height: 60)
        .shadow(color: .primary, radius: -10)
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10)
        .padding([.horizontal])
        .padding(.bottom)
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .modifier(OffsetModifier())
        .environmentObject(tabBarModel)
        .offset(y: tabBarModel.tabState == .floating ? 0 : bottomEdge)
    }
}
```

}

This is my ViewModifier I have included to create the scrolling animation.

```
struct OffsetModifier: ViewModifier {
@EnvironmentObject var model: TabBarViewModel
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                let minY = proxy.frame(in: .global).minY
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    let durationOffset: CGFloat = 35
                    
                    if minY < model.offset {
                        if model.offset < 0 && -minY > (model.lastStoredOffset + durationOffset) {
                            withAnimation(.easeOut.speed(1)) {
                                model.tabState = .floating
                            }
                            model.lastStoredOffset = -model.offset
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if minY > model.offset && -minY < (model.lastStoredOffset + durationOffset) {
                        withAnimation(.easeOut.speed(1)) {
                            model.tabState = .expanded
                        }
                        model.lastStoredOffset = -model.offset
                    }
                    
                    model.offset = minY
                }
                return Color.clear
            }
            ,alignment: .top
        )
}
```

}

Comment: A proxy instance maybe?

Comment: I'm confused because I simply made a state variable. It shouldn't be doing this. "@State var proxy: GeometryProxy"

Comment: You didn't provide the state variable with an initial value. If you need a `GeometryProxy` variable, you can't initialize your own proxy in the initializer. I would consider making it optional. Or not use it in a state variable.

Comment: When I do "var proxy: GeometryProxy," it gives me the same error. But what should I put in the placeholder? I want to be able to use the view universally without issue.

Comment: You need an initial value in either the declaration or as a parameter. What is the initial value?

Comment: I'm using the proxy for a scrolling animation like so. "let bottomEdge = proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom." So I don't really have an initial value.

Comment: I want to use the 'let' statement and again, I don't have an initial value. What is a proxy instance I can use?

Comment: Then make it optional and set its initial value to nil. It has to be initialized somehow no matter what declaration you use. but you should look at your approach too.

Comment: I tried using nil but it gave me even more errors. What is an alternative to my 'var' statement?

Comment: You might want to think about this a different way -- why do you need to pass a GeometryProxy? Why not just pass the dimensions down to the child view? Not seeing anything other than what you've provided, it's hard to reason about what's really needed here, but my suspicion is that you could make your situation easier by passing those dimensions (if those are even necessary...).

Comment: I have added more code to review. How do you pass the dimensions down to the child view?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. That code is far from minimal and far from reproducible but something to note is that at no point in your code do you give any value to that variable. What is the point? where would the value for that come from? You don't need it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time you ever use `proxy` is on this line:

```
let bottomEdge = proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

Therefore, there's no reason to pass in the entire `GeometryProxy` -- you can just pass in the bottom inset. Also, it definitely doesn't need to be a `@State` variable -- `@State` is used when the `View` needs to mutate its state over time -- this is just a parameter being passed in.

Change this line:

```
@State var proxy: GeometryProxy
```

to:

```
var bottomInset : CGFloat = 0
```

Because it has a default value, your preview can turn into this:

```
static var previews: some View {
    MathematicallyMainController()
}
```

If you really wanted to pass a value (say, from the parent of the `View`), you would do something like this:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in 
  //other view code...
  MathematicallyMainController(bottomInset: proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
  //other code...
}
```

There's also the option of moving the `GeometryReader` inside of `MathematicallyMainController`, but I'm assuming there's a reason you had it outside to begin with.

---

All of that being said, it looks like you have some unnecessary and unused code that you could clean up. For example, none of the `isSelectedA-E` variables ever get used. There's probably more here that can be refactored, but is outside of the scope of the present question.